# .net core routing via controller attribute

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, request

I have a controller that gets a route attribute:

```
[Route("api/v1/Admin/Keys")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{}
```

My Webproject has the following routes:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Admin}/{action=GetAllKeys}/{id?}");
});
```

**Error:**

> This localhost page can’t be found No web page was found for the web
>   address: http://localhost:60907/

When trying to go call a method on the controller which is also routed I keep getting the same.

If I remove the route attribute from the controller then this starts to work but I do not get the desired route.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Method that I am calling in the browser:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetAllKeys")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllKeys()
    {
        var data = await _manager.GetAllKeyTypes();

        return Ok(data);

    }
```

error:

> This localhost page can’t be found No web page was found for the web
>   address: http://localhost:60907/

EDIT2:

Now when removing the global route and just using the:

```
  [HttpGet("GetAllKeys")]
```

And using the following url: 
http://localhost:60907/GetAllKeys

This works but again it is not desiered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright...

Note to self...**do not** modify ports in .net core. 
I was experimenting with my API and my front-end project. 
Tried to put them on the same port but with a different access point. 
It worked as I thought which was that while the API was running then the node server could not start on the same port.

This however caused some kind of change somewhere which later when I changed back to the default port on the API never fully registered. 
I checked the launchSettings.json and modified it accordingly but still this did not work.

Final solution: 
Removed the project from my pc and got it back from my repo and now it works as it should with the original routes set.

Comment: Sounds right. Two applications can't bind to the same TCP port. If you want them working under the same port, you'd have to use a web server (like IIS) as a proxy so that the root of the domain forwards the request to your front end, and `/api` forwards to your API application.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have `[Route("api/v1/Admin/Keys")]` applied to the controller, then you would have to access the `GetAllKeys` action using `/api/v1/Admin/Keys/GetAllKeys`. I don't think that's what you want.

Try this:

```
[Route("api/v1/Admin/Keys")]
public class AdminController : Controller {

    [HttpGet("GetAllKeys")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllKeys()
    {
        var data = await _manager.GetAllKeyTypes();

        return Ok(data);

    }    
}
```

That tells it that every action in the `AdminController` is under `/api/v1/Admin/Keys`. Then the `HttpGet` attribute tells it that `GetAllKeys` should be available via `/api/v1/Admin/Keys/GetAllKeys`.

Once you set `Route` on the controller, it seems you have to use `HttpGet` to set the route on the action, otherwise it just doesn't work.

Comment: actually /api/v1/Admin/Keys/GetAllKeys is exactly what I want but I cant figure out why it is not working. url is "http://localhost:60907/api/v1/Admin/Keys/AllKeys" but I am geting: "This localhost page can’t be found"

Comment: @ThunD3eR you need to call [..]/GetAllKeys, not [..]/AllKeys

Comment: I've updated my answer. Set the route on the action using the `HttpGet` attribute, not `Route`.

Comment: Sorry m8, the image was a bit off. I am calling GetAllKeys

Comment: I tested this out in one of my apps. But note that in my Startup.cs, I have `app.UseMvc()` (no parameters).

Comment: Modified the application and made changes according to your specs, still the same

Comment: So you have `Route` set on the controller, and `HttpGet` set on the action?

Comment: Yes, Seems like something vent terribly wrong when I modified the port to a custom one.

Answer (score 1):

Convention routing is not used for controllers/actions with attribute routing configuration.

Attribute routing allows defining more than one route for the same action. You could simply do somehting like this:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
   [Route("")]
   [Route("Admin")]
   [Route("Admin/GetAllKeys")]
   [Route("api/v1/Admin/Keys")]
   public IActionResult GetAllKeys()
   { 
      ... 
   }
}
```